# JIRA change cloning behaviour so cloner is the reporter

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

using latest version of ScriptRunner and Jira.

How do I change cloning behaviour so the cloner becomes the reporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to make some magic. 
You can add a postfunction on create transition, and there choose "set field value with constant or groovy script", provided by scriptrunner.

Then in your script, look for "CLONE-" on your summary (or whatever expression you have set up for clonned issues). If the expression exists, you modify the reporter with the current user.

```
def componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
def currentUser = componentManager.jiraAuthenticationContext?.user
def permissionManager = componentManager.getPermissionManager()

if (permissionManager.hasPermission(Permissions.ASSIGNABLE_USER, issue, currentUser)) {
   MutableIssue mi = (MutableIssue)issue
   mi.setReporter(currentUser)  
   mi.store()
}
```

I think this is a good aproach

 
Let us know!
kind regards